# Security Audit Issue [For Asp.Net WebForms] : Source code disclosed

Tags: asp.net, webforms, audit

After the security audit of Asp.Net Application I have received a error report and one error is as Source Code Disclosed.
[image]

How Should I resolve this issue by preventing any person to view code?

Comment: I think that is common ASP.Net WebForms JS for button postbacks and the like that is included on every page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is **javascript code**, which is really common to be exposed/disclosed (*) simply because it is intended to be downloaded to the browser where it then runs. To label this a risk might seem abundant, although there could be some risk depending on what it is that you put in it.

The question is mainly: could this code be exploited, or could it be altered into something that is dangerous?

The answer is to not put secrets in it, and also to never rely on client-side-*only* logic and validation. Always have a server side equivalent that enforces whatever rules need to be enforced, and use SSL/https so the connection is secure, and then you should be good.

---

*(*) just hit F12, go to tab Sources or Debugger, and you'll see it here as well*